# Loading process and loading screens

Tags: c++

Well, the purpose of the loading screens is to display to the user that data is being loaded (downloaded) in the background.
But where can you make loading screens, can you do it on every program as startup for example and how to do so?

Comment: Standard `c++`  can't do that alone since there is no concept of a screen, GUI, widget ...

Comment: ***can you do it on every program as startup for example and how to do so?*** On any GUI framework I know there is an ability to create a dialog. In that dialog you can show a some type of progress bar widget.

Comment: In the Qt framework (which I use the most under MS Windows) there is a [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprogressdialog.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprogressdialog.html) which can show a progress bar pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have learned to display windows on the screen, you simply... display a window on the screen, with a progress bar, and every time your program loads something, you make the progress bar bigger.

This only makes sense if your program loads lots of things when it starts (such as large pictures or game levels). You can't make the OS display a loading screen when it loads *the program*. And you probably don't need to, because it's already fast enough.